# Story behind Injustice: Gods Among Us

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I have installed an started playing Injustice in my iPad Mini. but i'm still not clear about the story behind the creation of Insurgency and Regime in Injustice. I know that consoles comes with an story. Does any one knows the story behind it?

Comment: Joker kills Lois Lane, Superman goes crazy authoritarian, everyone involved starts being stupid to set up the conflict. The writing was *terrible*.

Comment: Any links to support your comment?? @Shadur

Comment: You could buy the related comics. http://www.comixology.com/Injustice-Gods-Among-Us-2013/comics-series/9821

Comment: You could, but I recommend against wasting your money on an awful story written to set up the premise to a grimdark fighting game full of bad characterization. There's samples over at scans-daily: http://scans-daily.dreamwidth.org/4311520.html is just one of them.

Comment: @Shadur - I'm only just seeing this now due to the bump, but the Injustice comics series has actually been very well received after the first few issues (my understanding is that it's GOOD writing, as opposed to what's actually in the game...). It also sold well enough to spawn a sequel after it finished - in fact, it was at the top of the sales charts for months.

Answer (score 2):

The story in the console version of the game doesn't actually explain much about the origins of the Regime and Insurgency. The story is more about how one universe of heroes tries to help the other universe of heroes situation.

The actual story of how it all begun is told through comics. The year one series of comics ended last year and there is now a year two series that started earlier this year.